# What are these words on the back of a קלף?

Tags: words, klaf-parchment

I recently saw a piece of קלף that had these words on the back:
[image: piece of parchment]
Note: I'm talking about the words towards the bottom of the parchment, not Hashem's name.
Notice how the words are written facing the other direction from the regular words.
I have 2 questions:

1. Does anyone know what these words say/mean?
2. What is the source for writing them on pieces of קלף?

Comment: That piece of klaf is, by the looks of it, a pretty low quality sefardi style mezuza. Where did you see it that you didn't know it was a mezuza?

Answer (score 2):

It's specifically written on a mezuzah.

See [here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/312102/jewish/Mezuzah-and-Astrology.htm):

> Rabbi Moses Isserlis (the ReMA) quotes the Hagahot Maimoni as the source for the custom of this inscription.

> This name is translated by Rebbeinu Bachya to mean, “He who dwells in the shelter of the Supreme One under the protection of Shad‑dai will endure.”

Comment: Note this custom is not universally followed (unlike the custom of writing שדי)

Comment: +1 - Fascinating!

Comment: The rama is yd 288:15, worth citing directly methinks